# How can I install Apache CXF?

Tags: eclipse, maven, cxf

I am trying to install Apache CXF (apache-cxf-2.4.1-src), in order to use /configure in eclipse for developing RESTful webservices.

I do not have apache installed at all and just installed eclipse. I download apache-cxf-2.4.1-src file and set up environment variables as I am supposed to.

But `mvn --Pfastinstall` in cmd prompt (when in directory c:\program files\apache-cxf-2.4.1-src) gives me this error message:

> mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command

Any help on getting this up and running would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apache tomcat is an application server and CXF is a JAX-RS implementation... very different things. Which are you trying to install?

Comment: @Jon: CXF (which is actually a JAX-WS and JAX-RS framework) typically needs a host servlet container in server mode; Tomcat's does very well at that.

Answer (score 3):

`mvn` stands for [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org), which is a build tool. You have to install maven to be able to run mvn commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: From Eclipse, go to Help, Install New Software.

For your URL put: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/

Checkmarck the 3 boxes, and press install. This will install maven. You can then create a new "Maven Project" in your workspace.

The dependencies you need for your pom.xml file to use CXF would be:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Good luck, hope I answered your question.